# Can't change font in Atom

Tags: fonts, atom-editor

I've tried setting various fonts in Atom (Fedora 21, Atom 0.187) but none seem to work.
I've tried setting Font Family to DejaVuSansMono and DroidSansMono but nothing changes (And yes they are installed)

Answer (score 6):

Solved by uncheck "Use Roboto Mono" in atom-material-ui theme =) It rewrites any other font family settings.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you set the font? 
I set DejaVuSansMono and DroidSansMono through settings view and both of them worked for me. Although I did test it only on Windows so far.

Have you tried to run with --safe option to see if some of packages doesn't interfere?

Comment: Yes I set it through Setting (ctrl+,) in Font Family. --safe did nothing (This is a fresh install of Atom). In Windows I was able to install and use DejaVuSansMono as expected but it still doesn't work in Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by disabling fonts atom package.

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed those font on your computer while Atom is open, restart Atom and try again.

I've succeeded doing so with `Droid Sans Mono`, `DejaVu Sans Mono` and `Droid Sans Mono Slashed`.